# Powershell and german umlauts in git branch names

Tags: git, powershell, batch-file, encoding

I have written a batch file which uses a powershell command to delete all local git branches except one to keep. If there are german umlauts used in branch names, it does not work.

> Switched to branch 'master'
>
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>
> Deleted branch DEV_API_StartenDesWorkers (was 61bec6d883b).
>
> error: branch 'DEV_â”œÂ£ersicht_Drucken' not found.
>
> error: branch 'test_prâ”œâ•�fung' not found.

The correct names are `DEV_Übersicht_drucken` and `test_prüfung`.

How can I achieve to delete these branches too?

This is the script:

```
@echo off
set KEEP=%1
IF [%KEEP%] == [] (goto eof)

git checkout %KEEP%

powershell "git branch -D @(git branch | select-string -NotMatch %KEEP% | ForEach-Object {$_.Line.Trim() })"

:eof
```

Comment: Git generally believes that all strings are UTF-8. Windows generally likes to use UTF-16-LE. They fight; one wins, one loses. :-) Slightly more seriously (but I don't use Windows and don't have PowerShell): you probably need to find some way to make your script output UTF-8 form.

Comment: You have an encoding issue with your shells. To narrow down the issue : can you run in a powershell.exe the `(git branch | ...)` part of your command ?

Comment: For starters I would recommend to stop running PowerShell commands from batch scripts.

Comment: I'd run the PowerShell script directly without using a batch file, if possible; batch files origin from the 1980s where no UTF-8 existed, and `cmd.exe` came up in the 1990s but UTF-8 became famous in the 2000s...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I'm by no means an expert in this stuff - the answer below fixes the symptoms for me, but your mileage may vary. Someone else with deeper knowledge of Windows codepages and the like might be able to give a better answer...

From what I've read, the core of the problem is that git is writing its output in utf8 as noted by @lorek and @LeGEC in the comments, but it's being mangled by the Windows codepage in use by the command prompt.

You can reproduce the behaviour with and without PowerShell:

```
c:\repo> git status
On branch test_prüfung
nothing to commit, working tree clean

c:\repo> git branch
* test_pr<C3><BC>fung

c:\repo> git branch | more
* test_pr├╝fung

c:\repo> powershell "$x = git branch; write-host $x"
* test_pr├╝fung

c:\repo> powershell "git branch -D @(git branch | select-string -NotMatch master | ForEach-Object {$_.Line.Trim() })"
error: branch '* test_pr├╝fung' not found.
```

What's happening is git is encoding its output into utf8 bytes and then the shell is decoding *that* using a different encoding - something like this:

```
$branch = "test_prüfung";
$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetBytes($branch);
$mangled = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437).GetString($utf8);
write-host $mangled
```

which outputs:

```
test_pr├╝fung
```

In my case, the magic "encoding 437" was determined by calling `chcp` to get the shell's current codepage:

```
C:\> chcp
Active code page: 437
```

And the [documentation for chcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) tells me that 437 is the codepage for `United States`.

What *seems* to fix the issue for me is to use [codepage 65001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) (i.e. UTF8) and then you get:

```
C:\repo> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

c:\repo> powershell "$x = git branch; write-host $x"
* test_prüfung
```

And this now works fine too:

```
c:\repo> powershell "git branch -D @(git branch | select-string -NotMatch master | ForEach-Object {$_.Line.Trim() })"
Deleted branch test_prüfung (was 1e9bc02).
```

Hope this helps a little bit...

Comment: Thanks a lot! `chcp 65001` was the missing piece of the puzzle! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set the output encoding to UTF8 (Which is used apparently for print derivation (write-output) and command line parameter passing).

I did it like this in the beginning of the file like this
(also note that I **saved it as UTF8-BOM** !!)

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)
# then something like
$branches = git branch -a --format '%(refname:lstrip=1)' 
$remoteBranches = $branches | Where-Object {$_ -like '*remotes/origin/*'} 
foreach($branch in $remoteBranches)
{
  write-output $branch
}
# gives me  
# remotes/origin/Bla_für_mich
# remotes/origin/Foo-änderung_müsste_rein
```

also keep in mind that newer Versions have a whole dictionary of variables for encodings for all theses aspects:
like  `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`