# How can I redirect input in PowerShell without a BOM?

Tags: powershell, encoding, pipe, byte-order-mark

I am trying to redirect input in PowerShell by:

```
Get-Content input.txt | my-program args
```

The problem is the piped UTF-8 text is preceded with a BOM (0xEFBBBF), and my program cannot handle that correctly.

A minimal working example:

```
// File: Hex.java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Hex {
    public static void main(String[] dummy) {
        int ch;
        try {
            while ((ch = System.in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%02X ", ch));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Then in PowerShell:

```
javac Hex.java
Set-Content textfile "ABC" -Encoding Ascii
# Now the content of textfile is 0x41 42 43 0D 0A
Get-Content textfile | java Hex
```

Or simply

```
javac Hex.java
Write-Output "ABC" | java Hex
```

In either case, the output is `EF BB BF 41 42 43 0D 0A`.

How can I pipe the text into the program without 0xEFBBBF?

Comment: what happens if you cast it as string explicitly? `[string](Get-Content input.txt) | my-program args`

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz The BOM is still here, but all newlines but the last one is converted to space. By the way, although my input.txt uses LF, the content passed via pipeline uses CR LF under both cases.

Comment: There is a big difference between `(Get-Content input.txt) |` which passes a single string (with newlines) to the pipeline and `Get-Content input.txt |` which passes multiple strings to the pipeline (where each string represents a line). Note that if you pass this to an variable (`String[]`) it might be separated by  a space or a newline depending on *how* you display it. Also note that for the later syntax your `my-program` needs to be able to `process` each individual item in the pipeline. Given the details in your question I doubt whether your program is actually doing that.

Comment: @iRon I do not quite understand that "`my-program` needs to be able to `precess` each item in the pipeline". In my case the program is a java program reading stdin. and the parentheses does not change the text read.

Comment: With all respect, I think you are too convinced the issue due to the BOM and not somewhere else. Normally `Get-Content` doesn't pass any BOM information. If you are not in a normal environment, you should supply details like OS, PowerShell version, etc. To confirm that you really retrieving any BOM information with `Get-Content` from your file, please show use the first few lines of your file: `Get-Content .\Bom.txt | Select -First 3 | ForEach-Object { "$([Byte[]]$_.ToCharArray())" }`. Please add these details **to the question**, see also: [mcve].

Comment: A comment in powershell starts with '#'.  Nice example otherwise.  I don't get a bom in osx.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details, it makes the issue more clear. Unfortunately I am not able to adequately respond right now, but believe your issue is related to this issue/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/1701026

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.  In windows 10 with ps 5.1 I get `41 42 43 0D 0A`.  It doesn't matter what the encoding of the file is.  What os and powershell version and java version are you?  PS 6 & 7 do the same.

Comment: @js2010 It is windows 10 version 2004, ps 5.1 and java 13. I will test on some other platforms later.

Comment: @iRon I read it before I asked here. That is about encoding of files and I don't know how that method can be used for pipelines.

Comment: And you're in the powershell console, not the ise or vscode or windows terminal?

Comment: @js2010 The problem exists in both powershell console and vscode for me. Java doesn't seem wrong, a c program can also read the bom. This does not happen in powershell 6+. Going to test on other versions of windows 10.

Comment: @user When PowerShell outputs to an external program (most .exe files), `$OutputEncoding` is used to determine the encoding. You could try `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)` before performing your commands.

Comment: `Set-Content 'D:\textfile.txt' "ABC" -Encoding Ascii; Get-Content 'D:\textfile.txt' -Encoding Byte | ForEach-Object { '{0:X2}' -f $_ }` returns `41` `42` `43` `0D` `0A`. No BOM whatsoever. As said in my answer check the OutputEncoding you have set in PowerShell and change that to use UFT8 without BOM if needed.

Comment: P.S. Did you by any change 'hack' the codepage with `chcp 65001` at some point? In that case, I recommend turning that back to `chcp 5129` for **English - New Zealand**. See [here](https://webcheatsheet.com/html/character_sets_list.php)

Comment: That version of Windows 10 is very new.  Does this show the BOM?  `get-content textfile | format-hex`.  It doesn't for me in osx, even if the file has a bom.  I'm in ps 7 rc1 though.

Comment: @js2010, your command doesn't apply: `Get-Content` _never_ sends a BOM through the pipeline, and `Format-Hex` is a PowerShell command, not an external program such as `java`. A BOM may appear for _unrelated_ reasons, irrespective of where the data came from: It can appear as a side effect of setting `$OutputEncoding` to an encoding _with a BOM_, which causes PowerShell to encode the string sent to _external programs_ with that BOM; AdminOfThings' comment shows the solution that _should_ work in a normal PS environment (there's something unusual going on on _one_ of user's machines).

Comment: I even tried win10 2004.  No bom.  Maybe you made a special config to $outputencoding.  Check your $profile.

Comment: @mklement0 You're right.  The bom didn't show up in format-hex, even with [Text.Encoding]::Utf8 in windows 10 2004.  My money is on him setting that encoding in his $profile.  The $profile is different in ps core.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>Note:

The following contains general information that in a normally functioning PowerShell environment would explain the OP's symptom. That the solution doesn't work in the OP's case is owed to machine-specific causes that are unknown at this point.

**This answer is about sending BOM-less UTF-8 *to* an *external program*; if you're looking to make your PowerShell console windows use UTF-8 in *all* respects, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375).**</sup>

To ensure that your Java program receives its input UTF-8-encoded *without a BOM*, **you must set `$OutputEncoding` to a [`System.Text.UTF8Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.UTF8Encoding) instance that does *not* emit a BOM**:

```bash
# Assigns UTF-8 encoding *without a BOM*.
# PowerShell uses this encoding to encode data piped to external programs.
# $OutputEncoding defaults to ASCII(!) in Windows PowerShell, and more sensibly
# to BOM-*less* UTF-8 in PowerShell [Core] v6+
$OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)
```

**Caveats**:

- **Do NOT use the seemingly equivalent `New-Object Text.Utf8Encoding $false`**, because, due to the bug described in [GitHub issue #5763](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5763), it won't work if you assign to `$OutpuEncoding` in a non-global scope, such as in a *script*. In PowerShell v4 and below, use
  `(New-Object Text.Utf8Encoding $false).psobject.BaseObject` as a workaround.
- **Windows 10 version 1903 and up** allow you to **set BOM-less UTF-8 as the *system-wide default* encoding** (although note that the feature is still classified as *beta* as of version 20H2) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375); [***fixed in PowerShell 7.1***] **in PowerShell [Core] up to v7.0**, **with this feature turned on, the above technique is *not* effective, due to a presumptive .NET Core *bug*** that causes a UTF-8 BOM *always* to be emitted, irrespective of what encoding you set `$OutputEncoding` to (the bug is possibly connected to [GitHub issue #28929](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28929)); **the only solution is to turn the feature *off***, as shown in [imgx64's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513730/45375).

If, by contrast, you use `[Text.Encoding]::Utf8`, you'll get  a [`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) instance *with BOM* - which is what I suspect happened in your case.

---

Note that this problem is unrelated to the source encoding of any *file* read by `Get-Content`, because **what is sent through the PowerShell pipeline is never a stream of *raw bytes*, but *.NET objects*, which in the case of `Get-Content` means that .NET *strings* are sent** ([`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String), internally a sequence of UTF-16 code units).

**Because you're piping to an *external program* (a Java application, in your case), PowerShell character-encodes the (stringified-on-demand) objects sent to it based on [preference variable `$OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables)**, and the resulting encoding is what the external program receives.

**Perhaps surprisingly, even though BOMs are typically only used *in files*, PowerShell respects the BOM setting of the encoding assigned to `$OutputEncoding` also *in the pipeline*, prepending it to the first line sent (only).**

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for more information about how PowerShell handles pipeline input for and output from external programs, including how **it is `[Console]::OutputEncoding` that matters when PowerShell interprets data received *from* external programs**.

---

To illustrate the difference using your sample program (note how using a PowerShell string literal as input is sufficient; no need to read from a file):

```bash
# Note the EF BB BF sequence representing the UTF-8 BOM.
# Enclosure in & { ... } ensures that a local, temporary copy of $OutputEncoding
# is used.
PS> & { $OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8; 'hö' | java Hex }
EF BB BF 68 C3 B6 0D 0A

# Note the absence of EF BB BF, due to using a BOM-less
# UTF-8 encoding.
PS> & { $OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false); 'hö' | java Hex }
68 C3 B6 0D 0A
```

In *Windows PowerShell*, where `$OutputEncoding` defaults to ASCII(!), you'd see the following with the default in place:

```bash
# The default of ASCII(!) results in *lossy* encoding in Windows PowerShell.
PS> 'hö' | java Hex 
68 3F 0D 0A
```

Note that `3F` represents the literal `?` character, which is what the non-ASCII `ö` character was transliterated too, given that it has no representation in ASCII; in other words: *information was lost*.

*PowerShell [Core] v6+* now sensibly defaults to BOM-less UTF-8, so the default behavior there is as expected.
While BOM-less UTF-8 is PowerShell [Core]'s *consistent* default, also for cmdlets that read from and write to files, on *Windows* `[Console]::OutputEncoding` still reflects the active OEM code page by default as of v7.0, so to correctly capture output from UTF-8-emitting external programs, it must be set to `[Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)` as well - see [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233).

Comment: I cannot reproduce in a virtual machine (Windows 10 build 1909) either. Probably something is wrong on my end. Thank you anyway. Just for reference, it is Windows 10 build 19559, Powershell 5.1.19559.1000. The problem happens in PS console, vscode console and ISE, but not for Powershell v6+.

Comment: Thanks, @user. Intriguing symptom; do tell us if you ever find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the OutputEncoding to UTF-8 without BOM:

```
# Keep the current output encoding in a variable
$oldEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding

# Set the output encoding to use UTF8 without BOM
[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false

Get-Content input.txt | my-program args

# Reset the output encoding to the previous
[console]::OutputEncoding = $oldEncoding
```

---

If the above has no effect and your program does understand UTF-8, but only expects it to be without the 3-byte BOM, then you can try removing the BOM from the content and pipe the result your program

```
(Get-Content 'input.txt' -Raw -Encoding UTF8) -replace '^\xef\xbb\xbf' |  my-program args
```

---

If ever you have 'hacked' the codepage with `chcp 65001`, I recommend turning that back to `chcp 5129` for English - New Zealand. See [here](https://webcheatsheet.com/html/character_sets_list.php).

Comment: @user Please try the alternative I have edited in. Since we do not know your `my-program` and have no idea what the parameter `args` does, it is difficult to understand what is going on there..

Comment: Doesn't work either. I do not think my program is a problem because I wrote a small program that merely print hexadecimal value of each byte from stdin, and find it print efbbbf first.

Comment: @user Then I suggest you edit that program and have it detect if a BOM is present and if so skip those bytes. You can then also include other encoding byte order marks: `\x00\x00\xfe\xff    UTF-32 big-endian /// \xff\xfe\x00\x00    UTF-32, little-endian /// \xfe\xff            UTF-16, big-endian /// \xff\xfe            UTF-16, little-endian /// \xef\xbb\xbf        UTF-8`. This will make for a much more useful utility I would say because as it turns out now it can only handle UTF8 witout BOM..

Comment: `+1` for the information about changing encoding from within PowerShell. It apparently doesn't fix this issue, but it might be the best answer to this one: [How to store directional arrow character in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60093096/1701026)

Comment: @iRon Thanks. I didn't see that question before, but I do believe the answer for that one is using the outputencoding. (cannot test because I don't have tshark.exe)

Comment: `[Console]::OutputEncoding` only matters with respect to how PowerShell interprets output _from_ external programs, whereas what matters here is how PowerShell encodes data sent _to_ external programs, which is controlled by the `$OutputEncoding` preference variable. Note that if `input.txt` has a UTF-8 BOM, what `Get-Content` reads into .NET string (before further processing) - sensibly - does _not_ have this BOM.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for explaining. Pretty confusing naming there, so I tend to not keep them apart..

Comment: Fully agreed re the confusing naming; also, arguably it should be a _single_ preference variable that controls the encoding for both sending to and receiving from external programs.

Answer (score 0):

Although [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142347/380722) worked for me on one PC, it didn't work on another PC.

The reason was that I had the `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support` checkbox selected in `Language` → `Administrative language settings` → `Change system locale`.

I unchecked it and now `$OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($false)` works as expected.

It's odd that enabling it forces BOM, but I guess it's beta for a reason.

[image: Uncheck Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support]